# Docker container cannot copy file into volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am pretty new to docker, so i might be doing something truly wrong

I need to share some files between docker containers, using a docker compose file

I have already created a volume like this

```
docker volume create shared
```

After that i can check the created volume

```
docker volume inspect shared
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-03-08T14:54:57-05:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/shared/_data",
        "Name": "shared",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

My docker-compose.yaml file looks like this

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  service1:
    build:
      context: Service1
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: server1-server
    volumes:
       - shared:/shared

  service2:
    build:
      context: Service2
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: server2-server
    volumes:
       - shared:/shared

volumes:
  shared:
     external: true
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this (just for testing purposes)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env

RUN echo "test" > /shared/test.info
```

When i issue a docker-compose up command i get this error

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /shared/test.info: Directory nonexistent
```

If i modify the Dockerfile to this

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN cp *.csproj /shared/
```

I get this error

```
cp: cannot create regular file '/shared/': Not a directory
```

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Comment: `RUN mkdir /shared`?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Max, that helped with the writing part; but now i need to read that stored data in another container; what should i do ? RUN mount or something ? because in the second container the problem is that i cannot mkdir the same directory

Comment: Could you expand your `docker-compose.yml` to include the second service?

Comment: i edited the original post to reflect the second service, the second Dockerfile uses the same image and only does a RUN ls -ln /shared but /shared does not exists

Comment: i finally decided against my first approach and now am building the dependencies for the service in the same image, as a previous step to build the main application; this question should be closed now

Answer (score 4):

A Dockerfile contains instructions to create an image. After the image is built, the image can be run as a container.

A volume is attached when launching containers.

It thus makes no sense to use Dockerfile instructions to copy a file into a volume while building an image.

Volumes are generally used to share runtime data between containers, or to keep data after a container is stopped.